# AngularJS reloading ngTable from ng-change event

Tags: angularjs, ngtable, angular-promise

I am populating ngTable using the following which works fine:

```
      $scope.data = ClientService.query(
        {
            state: $scope.currentStateId,
            parentId: $scope.parentId
        });

    $scope.data.$promise.then(function (data) {
        $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams(
            {
                page: 1,                        // show first page
                count: $scope.pageCount,        // count per page
                sorting: { Name: 'asc' },
                filter: { Name: ''}
            },
            {
                total: data.length,
                getData: function ($defer, params) {
                    var orderedData = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')(data, params.filter()) : data;
                    orderedData = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')(orderedData, params.orderBy()) : orderedData;
                    params.total(orderedData.length); // set total for recalc pagination

                    $scope.accounts = orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
                    $defer.resolve($scope.accounts);
                }
            });
    });
```

I now wish to update the ngTable from an ng-change event which sets a new $scope.currentStateId as follows:

```
 $scope.stateChange = function () {
        //$state.go('root.account.clients.list', { state: $scope.currentStateId, parentId : $scope.parentId }, { reload : true })
        //var sel = $scope.currentStateId;
        $scope.data = ClientService.query(
            {
                state: $scope.currentStateId,
                parentId: $scope.parentId
            });
       $scope.tableParams.reload();
    };
```

The ClientService.query hits the server with the correct parameters and returns the correct data but the ngTable is not updated.

Can someone please help.

Comment: What does `ClientService.query` look like? Does it return a promise?

Comment: its out of the box Angular $Resource RESTful API

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Update (correct answer)

Promises, by design, can be resolved only once. As a result, nesting `new ngTableParams` inside of `$scope.data.$promise.then(function (data) {` limits your ability to update the data at a later point.

Instead, put the callback inside of the `getData` function so that you can reset `$scope.data` with a new promise before calling `$scope.tableParams.reload()`:

```
$scope.data = ClientService.query({
    ...
});

$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({                     
    ...
    getData: function ($defer, params) {
        $scope.data.$promise.then(function (data) {
            var orderedData = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')(data, params.filter()) : data;
            ...
            $defer.resolve($scope.accounts);
        });
    }
});

$scope.stateChange = function () {    
    $scope.data = ClientService.query({
        ...
    });

    $scope.tableParams.reload();
};
```

---

#### Previous Answer (incorrect)

You have a synchronous function call (your ngTable update) following an asynchronous call (the `ClientService` query). So, the table update executes before the data comes back.

Wrap the table update call in callback that fires once the promise is resolved:

```
$scope.data = ClientService.query(
{
    state: $scope.currentStateId,
    parentId: $scope.parentId
});

$scope.data.$promise.then(function (data) {
    $scope.tableParams.reload();
};
```

Comment: Thanks Marc, but still not updating ngTable.

Comment: Please try this: https://gist.github.com/marcolepsy/ea77c8daa1918e992d20 If it works, I'll update my answer. If it doesn't and you're still stumped, please update your question with a simplified Plunker/Fiddle/whatever which demonstrates the issue.